# Erdős-Rényi model, network reliability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-graphs

I recently came across the Erdős-Rényi model random graph model, which indeed fascinated me with its beauty and simplicity. I've started to dig into it and saw the following theorem (listed on Wiki, for instance):

Let $G(n, p)$ be a random graph containing $n$ vertices, then the following holds, for $p=\cfrac{c\cdot \log{n}}{n}$:

- if $c > 1$, then graph will asymptotically almost surely be connected;
- if $c < 1$, then graph will asymptotically almost surely have some isolated vertices and asymptotically almost surely be disconnected

The question is, what can we say about $c=1$? Is there anything interesting to say about this parameter value?

I would appreciate any response.

Answer (score 2):

When
$$
p=\frac{\ln n}{n}+\frac{s+o(1)}{n}
$$
for some fixed $s\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(G(n,p)\text{ is connected})\to e^{-\exp(-s)}.
$$
(see, e.g., Theorem 7.3 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=o9WecWgilzYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Random+Graphs+Second+Edition+B%C3%89LA+BOLLOB%C3%81S&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHqYWJn6_tAhXBCuwKHV7oCBUQ6wEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=Theorem%207.3&f=false)).